# How to print the pictures in crystal report

Tags: image, printing, crystal-reports, report

I have a customer number and the image I want to look and print output
How do you print the pictures in crystal report

Comment: Have you tried something!!!

Answer (score 0):

private void LoadImage(DataRow objDataRow, string strImageField, string FilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath,
                           System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
                byte[] Image = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(Image, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                fs.Close();
                objDataRow[strImageField] = Image;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Response.Write("" + ex.Message + "");
            }
        }

؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟؟
................................

OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter myAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            Cmd.CommandText = "select CCont,image from SaveImage where CCont='" + textBoxet.Text + "'";
            Cmd.Connection = myConn;

```
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = Cmd;

        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            myAdapter.Fill(ds.Tables[0]);
            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }


        for (int index = 0; index < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; index++)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[index]["image"].ToString() != "")
            {
                string s = ds.Tables[0].Rows[index]["image"].ToString();

                if (File.Exists(s))
                {
                    LoadImage(ds.Tables[0].Rows[index], "image", s);
                }
                else
                {
                    LoadImage(ds.Tables[0].Rows[index], "image",
                              "DefaultPicturePath");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                LoadImage(ds.Tables[0].Rows[index], "image",
                          "DefaultPicturePath");
            }
        }

        try
        {
            // Finally display report in crystal report viewer
            ReportDocument crDoc = new ReportDocument();
            crDoc.Load("CrystalReport1.rpt");
            crDoc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
```

}